# Ionic - Google Speech to Text

Tags: android, ionic-framework

In my ionic app, I have the following textbox toward the bottom of my input form:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="item item-divider">Note</div>
    <label class="item item-input">
        <textarea rows='8' ng-model="note"></textarea>
    </label>
</div>
```

I deployed the app to android phone and when I click into the textbox, the android keyboard appears as expected.  If I click on the mic on the keyboard, google speech to text appears, which is great, but occasionally closes right away.  This happens about 20% of the time, but I cant figure out why. I know I have network / wifi access because it will work if I attempt it again in the same spot. I also tried scrolling all the way to the bottom of the page, but same result.

If anyone has an idea, how to prevent the google speech to text from closing occasionally, I would appreciate it.